Why do we need two functions: update() and set() in Angular's signals?
I read about the signals in Angular and there are two methods to alter the current value: by set() and update().

Angular has adapted Signals into the framework and have started to build a set of new features that utilize Signals as their cornerstone. Using update allows us to access the current value of the signal , and set allows us to set a new value without caring about the current value.

What puzzles me is that I don't understand how both are needed (although I see that each can be used). It's clear that I can. But why?
Let's say we define an instance like so.
siggy = signal(4);

Then, we can set an absolute value using both of the following ways.
this.siggy.set(1337);
this.siggy.update((a) => 1337);

But we also can use both of those to set a relative one (alter the current).
this.siggy.set(this.siggy() + 1);
this.siggy.update((a) => a + 1);

It seem superfluous to provide multiple ways to reach the same result. Such redundancy is a sign of bad design (or possibly syntactic sugar for DX purposes). I do not in any way suggest that the great folks on Angular team made a poor design! Nor do I see any increase in smoothness. (In fact, even the Angular blog mentions the usage of this.counter.set(this.counter()+1)...)
My conclusion is that there are (edge) cases that I'm ignorant of. What am I missing?
edit
I kept on researching and discovered even more confusing facts. In addition to set() and update(), there's also mutate() (So much for Complete Guide, thank you very much). And this one can be used as below (which I intuitively did).
let siggy = signal([1,2,3]);
...
this.siggy.mutate(a => a.push(4));

It compiles. The problem is that it won't do anything: no change, no update, no nothing! Apparently, I have to do like so.
this.siggy.mutate(a => a = [...a, 4]);

But that's redundant to the others! I can understand (although I disagree) that someone may want to use set() to indicate a replacement, while keeping update() for alterations. But even then, mutate() brings no extra info as it's an update (which also sets it).
It seems like there's only siggy.alter(), siggy.change() and siggy.modify() missing. It smells fishy to me. I'm certain it's me not getting the actual reason why set/update/mutate are all required.
What is the technical reason? What can't be done with each of those?

You could obviously use update to just set a value and ignore the current value. But then there is a) an unused variable and b) the intent is unclear and I as a developer have to check the actual logic inside the update block (which might be more complex than a single line) in order to realise that the update is just a set operation. Just having a dedicated method for that case feels more concise. I feel like both just have their use cases. And the case this.siggy.set(this.siggy() + 1); - please don't do that. It feels REALLY clunky and I would not bet on it working like expected :D

here are a good discursion about Signals. In the second part says that "While the API surface has 3 different methods (set, update, mutate) of changing signal’s value, the .set(newValue) is the only fundamental operation that we need in the library. The other 2 methods are just syntactic sugar, convenience methods that could be expressed as .set."

@Eliseo That confirms my impression. Still, I can't see why such a redundancy. I can see, as Loop suggests above, that it's visually indicating reset from alteration. Fine. Not my taste but I can get that someone might appreciate it. But why two redundancies?! It bugs me. Bugs me a lot.

update() just calls set() internally: source on GitHub so this question probably doesn't have a convincing/empirical answer unless someone can find one in the comments on the related RFCs from the Angular team members.

It looks like mutate() was dropped entirely: CHANGELOG on GitHub.

I'd guess that set() should probably be an overload of update() with a defaulted updater parameter (the current value is not required to determine the new value). That would have left us with just update(T) and update(T -> T) (two overloads) and no set()/mutate() to imply that mutations could be change detected.

@DM First of all: I do not in any way pretend to know better nor have the balls to pass critique against the awesome devs creating Angular. I'm not in their league by any measures. Now that being abundantly clearly stated: the signals in Angular feels like a premature ejaculation to me. Those multiple methods being dropped, redundant etc. Also, signal within a component was made available in v16 while the model signal in v18 (which took me a while to discover). It feels like someone in the marketing got a bit trigger happy. No bueno... It so React'ish...

As @DM show in the source it's the same. I imagine some kind of nostalgic about lambda functions

TL;DR: just set is needed as you mention, update was introduced for convenience & mutate was eventually removed as essentially same as set
You can see the full discussion in the Signals APIs RFC

Well... crap! The weekly disappointment. I was hoping for some deeper technicality that would educate me on the internals of Angular. So big fuss for nothing. At least, not I know. Here's your 100 smackaroonies. Enjoy!

As far as I knew,
this.siggy.set(this.siggy() + 1); // Not a correct way to implement

and
this.siggy.update((a) => a + 1); // here `a` will be the existing value of `siggy`.

are totally different. It'll not work as the way you assume.
As these methods are asynchronous, the behaviour will be different.
The set method will replace the value with the old one.
whereas the update will mutate/update the old value.
Ex:
this.siggy.update((a) => a + 1);
console.log(this.siggy()); // Here the value will not be latest one.

The same scenario I faced in React.js while using the useState hook and that's why there are separate methods update and set.

You say "As these methods are asynchronous", Really, I think that it's not, signal are always synchronous (so are the same). The only it's not write and get some kind of "lambda"

With all respect for your experience, comparing Angular to React is usually a very bad idea and easily leads to confusion due to false similarities in concepts. I can't say for sure that set/update are fundamentally different in Angular's signals and Reacts states but as far I dare, I wouldn't consider them alike. Also, I wonder why you mean by the first sample being invalid (or incorrect to implement)? It does work and there's no difference according to the Angular blog when I read it. Are you suggesting that from the perspective of React syntax?

"The set method will replace the value with the old one. whereas the update will mutate/update the old value." This statement makes no sense to me. It's just different words for the same event, isn't it? Setting an entirely new value and updating the old value to en entirely new value is the same operation, right? It's not like the new value of 7 magically remembers being -3 once upon a time in its former incarnation. What are we missing here, please? It seems like a distinction without a difference.

You are asking for a technical necessity leading to the decision to have separate methods for working with the previous value and not working with the previous value, just overriding it.
From what I know so far about JavaScript itself and drawing on my experience with React, it would have been technically possible to use the same function name for both. In React, you can do both with the same function, see this example:
export default function MyComponent() {
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    // version 1
    setCurrentValue(() => currentValue + 1)
    // version 2
    setCurrentValue((oldValue) => oldValue + 1)

  }

  return (<>
    {currentValue}
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Add 1</button>
  </>);
}

This was confusing to me when I started with React because having a function called "set" that let me do stylistically very different things, I had to look sharply at the way it was used. So I personally think having more descriptive names for these two things makes sense and leads to more expressive, more readable code.
TLDR: Javascript allows overriding. Therefore there is no technical necessity to use two separate functions. The Angular maintainers could have decided for either version - having separate function names or overriding them based on using their signature. As explained above, I think it does make sense to have different functions for different purposes so everything has its own name. But ultimately, it is pure preference.

This question is about Angular not React. I think it's dangerous to consider those as comparable items and what makes sense in React, doesn't in Angular (more often than people expect). I was hoping for a technical reasoning from the perspective of Angular because I see absolutely zero gain in having it. In React, it's sadly necessary. But in my (opinionated and biased) view, it says more about React...   :)

When you need to update the value regardless of its previous value, use set().
this.siggy.set(10);

If that new value is based on the previous one, use update() instead of set().
this.siggy.update((a) => a + 1);


Thanks for the suggestion. However, that's not really answering the question asked. I'm not asking how to use those nor when. I simply fail to see the point of them both coexisting. We don't really need both of them...
